# Kafka Streams API: I am joining two KStreams of empmodel

Tags: apache-kafka-streams, kafka-join

```java
final KStream<String, EmpModel> empModelStream = getMapOperator(empoutStream);
final KStream<String, EmpModel> empModelinput = getMapOperator(inputStream);

//  empModelinput.print();
//  empModelStream.print();

empModelStream.join(empModelinput, new ValueJoiner<EmpModel, EmpModel, Object>() {

    @Override
    public Object apply(EmpModel paramV1, EmpModel paramV2) {
        System.out.println("Model1 "+paramV1.getKey());
        System.out.println("Model2 "+paramV2.getKey());
        return paramV1;
    }

},JoinWindows.of("2000L"));
```

I get error:

> Invalid topology building: KSTREAM-MAP-0000000003 and KSTREAM-MAP-0000000004 are not joinable

Answer (score 3):

If you want to join two `KStreams` you must ensure that both have the same number of partitions. (cf. *"Note"* box in http://docs.confluent.io/current/streams/developer-guide.html#joining-streams)

If you use Kafka `v0.10.1+`, repartitioning will happen automatically (cf. http://docs.confluent.io/current/streams/upgrade-guide.html#auto-repartitioning).

For Kafka `v0.10.0.x` you have two options:

1. ensure that the original input topics do have the same number of partitions
2. or, add a call to `.through("my-repartitioning-topic")` to one of the `KStream`s before the join. You need to create the topic `"my-repartioning-topic"` with the right number of partitions (ie, same number of partitions as the second `KStream`'s original input topic) before you start your Streams application